# What is the HTML form input equivalent for a JSON array?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json, jackson

I am trying to send a JSON array in the request body of an HTTP POST endpoint which returns a CSV file.

```
var config = {
    foo: ['bar']
}
$http.post(url, config).success(...).error(...);
```

The Java class representing this config input looks like this:

```
@JsonProperty List<String> foo;
```

The above `$http.post` works fine, except that I need to open a download prompt for the CSV file. I need to support IE8 so I am constructing a form similar to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/DavidMah/3533415).

```
var form = $("<form></form>").attr("action", url)
                             .attr("method", "post");
form.append($("<input/>").attr("type", "hidden")
                         .attr("name", "foo[]")
                         .attr("value", "bar"));
form.appendTo($("body"))
    .submit()
    .remove();
```

The above code does not seem to send a properly formatted JSON array for Jackson to deserialize. According to Chrome dev tools, the `$http.post` version sends `foo: ["bar"]` but the `form` version sends `foo[]: "bar"`.

How can I POST the JSON array I want using HTML forms?

Comment: There is no equivalent, a form can't produce JSON, only www-urlencoded data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent as far as I know. You need to `POST` the HTML form using JavaScript by constructing (and later sending in the request) a JSON payload with the values in the HTML form (kind of weird but hey, you are sending data!).

Or just `POST` the form and build a JSON on the server side.